# SQL Server BULK INSERT: why "The FIRSTROW attribute is not intended to skip column headers"?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx
I can read that:

> The FIRSTROW attribute is not intended to skip column headers.
>   Skipping headers is not supported by the BULK INSERT statement. When
>   skipping rows, the SQL Server Database Engine looks only at the field
>   terminators, and does not validate the data in the fields of skipped
>   rows.

But I would like to do exactly this. Why is this not intended? Can I expect any problems when I do skip headers with FIRSTROW = 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the SQL Server Database Engine looks only at the field terminators

That's your answer.  If your column headers have names that include field terminators, the system will find the wrong number of fields in the first line, and great hilarity will thus ensue.  You can imagine that in all the world's files, some column had

```
Years, since 1970
```

as a header.  Clear enough to the human, but the machine has only *rules*.

In case you're not aware, your `bulk insert` will fail in the general case for CSV files.  CSV format is quite variable, and more complex than what `bulk insert` can interpret correctly.  Specifically, there are quoting rules that allow commas to be included among the data.  SQL Server won't honor the quotes. It will interpret the comma as a separator regardless.  Like the man says,

> the SQL Server Database Engine looks only at the field terminators

Comment: Have I understood correctly that this answer boils down to "It most cases it will work just fine, particularly with anythign that a naive programmer would expect to work ... it just won't work for EVERY case, particularly not for every edge case that CSV admits".

Comment: I wouldn't venture to say "most" CSV files are strictly comma-delimited, with no quoting, no.  If you have control over how the CSV file is produced, and can therefore ensure no quoting will occur, you would have a particular kind of CSV file that is *also* a valid text file that happens to use comma as a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

It will work fine, but it´s need the first row be same format (mean that header must have same FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR) and when use firstrow = 2 then that data will be inserted from the second row.
Example if I have CSV file what to import and the first line is column header my code will be like this

```
BULK INSERT myTable
FROM 'C:\myTable.csv'
WITH
(
   FIRSTROW = 2,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```